# meteor js create mongodb database hook to store data from API at fixed interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

tldr - What is the best pattern create a 'proprietary database' with data from an API?  In this case, using Meteor JS and collections in mongo db.

**Steps**
1.  Ping API
2.  Insert Data into Mongo at some interval

In lib/collections.js

```
Prices = new Mongo.Collection("prices");
```

Basic stock api call, in `server.js`:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getPrice: function () {
    var result = Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://api.fakestockprices.com/ticker/GOOG.json");
    return result.data;
  }  
});
```

Assume the JSON is returned clean and tidy, and I want to store the entire object (how you manipulate what is returned is not important, storing the return value is)

We could manipulate the data in the `Meteor.method` function above but should we?  In Angular services are used to call API, but its recommended to modularize and keep the API call in its own function.  Lets borrow that, and `Meteor.call` the above `getPrice`.

Assume this also done in `server.js` (please correct).

```
Meteor.call("getPrice", function(error, result) {
  if (error)
      console.log(error)

    var price = result;

    Meteor.setInterval(function() {
     Prices.insert(price);
    }, 1800000); // 30min

});
```

Once in the db, a pub/sub could be established, which I'll omit and [link to this overview](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [synced-cron package](https://atmospherejs.com/percolatestudio/synced-cron).

With a cron job it's pretty easy, just call your method:

```
// server.js

SyncedCron.start();

SyncedCron.add({

  name: "get Price",

  schedule: function(parser){
    return parser.text('every 30 minutes');
  },

  job: function(){
    return Meteor.call("getPrice");
  }
});
```

Then in `getPrice` you can do `var result = HTTP.call(/* etc */);` and `Prices.insert(result);`.  You would want some additional checks of course, as you have pointed out.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! For anyone curious the full working code is contained in this commit: https://github.com/DeBraid/bitcoin-prices/commit/2a9337a8fbeaa8c2d586f60195a32b297ab4f3e5